# Textbox stile like underlined

Tags: wpf, xaml, textbox, styles

I would like to style my textboxes to display like just an underlined area.
Similar to image below...

[image]

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: Think you could do it will a border.  If not insert a row with an underline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set on every textbox (or with a general style..):

```
BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" Background="Transparent"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put a border on the bottom

```
<TextBox BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,0,2" 
         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="40" />
```